# PySpark incrementally add id based on another column and previous data

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Incrementally derive ID from a `name` column and on next load if there are new values added to that `name` column then assign need ID which is not already assigned to previous data

Example - first load:

| Name |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| b |
| a |

Result

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | b |
| 1 | a |

Next load:

| Name |
| --- |
| a |
| b |
| b |
| a |
| c |
| d |
| c |

Result:

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 2 | b |
| 1 | a |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |
| 3 | c |

As described in question looking for a solution in PySpark

Comment: What if next load has repeated names e.g. "a", "b" again?

Comment: As 'a' & 'b' has already Id assigned it would get the same id for next load as well

Answer (score 1):

You can create additional dataframe `df_map` where you store your IDs between loads. If you need to, you can save and restore this dataframe from the disk.

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['a']],
    schema=["name"]
)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    data=[['a'], ['b'], ['b'], ['a'], ['c'], ['d'], ['c'], ['0']],
    schema=["name"]
)

w = Window.orderBy('name')

# create empty map
df_map = spark.createDataFrame([], schema='name string, id int')
df_map.show()

# get additional name->id map for df1
n = df_map.select(F.count('id').alias('n')).collect()[0].n
df_map = df1.subtract(df_map.select('name')).withColumn('id', F.row_number().over(w) + F.lit(n)).union(df_map)
df_map.show()

# map can be saved to disk between runs

# get additional name->id map for df2
n = df_map.select(F.count('id').alias('n')).collect()[0].n
df_map = df2.subtract(df_map.select('name')).withColumn('id', F.row_number().over(w) + F.lit(n)).union(df_map)
df_map.show()

# join to get the final dataframe
df2.join(df_map, on='name').show()
```

Comment: The operation should be dynamic in the sense there is a scheduled trigger that auto triggers everyday with insert/update in rows, so looking for a logic that runs on memory at that point of time to derive Id

Answer (score 0):

You can use window and dense_rank. The code below will make dataframe sorted by 'name' column and give each unique name an incremental unique id.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
from pyspark.sql import Window as W

window = W.orderBy('name')
(
    df
    .withColumn('id', F.dense_rank().over(window))
).show() 

+----+---+
|name| id|
+----+---+
|   a|  1|
|   a|  1|
|   b|  2|
|   b|  2|
|   c|  3|
|   c|  3|
|   d|  4|
+----+---+
```

Comment: This will reassign all IDs depending on the ordering of names. Try inserting '0'.